# Why does a WPF Textbox DesiredHeight gives space for a new line too soon?

Tags: c#, wpf, text, textbox, height

I have a TextBox inside a UserControl on the left, which get filled with text from the TextBox on the right. The idea is whatever text I type on the right, is visible on the left and the UserControl changes in height depending on how much text is written:
[image]

The code I use is:

```
 argTextBox.Measure(new Size(argTextBox.ActualWidth, Double.PositiveInfinity));

 var tempNewSize = new Size(argTextBox.DesiredSize.Width, argTextBox.DesiredSize.Height);
```

In which argTextBox equals the textbox on the left. Somehow the height from tempNewSize is already 47.96px with one line. With two lines i get an equal amount of space extra:
[image]

Interesting to understand that after I now finished the word text in the second line, at the 'x'  character I already get a third line in height, although the x is still place visually on the second line.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? There is no extra lines in the right textfield, I also checked the strings at runtime to see if there was extra lines in the string.

Edit:
Seems that the measuring method also takes the margin in its calculations. My later code added the extra margin:

```
var tempTextHeight = tempSize.Height;
var tempMargin = 15;

this.Height = tempMargin * 2 + tempTextHeight;
```

By removing the margin the extra spaces problem is solved, yet the start of a new line too soon is not.

Answer (score -1):

The solution to getting a new line too soon is as follows:

With the measuring method the margin is not taken in calculation, so it needs to be added extra:

```
 argTextBox.Measure(new Size(argTextBox.ActualWidth + (argTextBox.Margin.Left + argTextBox.Margin.Right), Double.PositiveInfinity));
```

[image]